# Android Studio error: "Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O"

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, realm

Updated Android Studio to 3.4 and after that when running the project, then I get error "Error: Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)".

I have updated realm from 5.8.0 to 5.9.0. 
I have already tried adding

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

to app level build gradle.

Only thing that I have found is when I go File > Project Structure > Modules

Then under Source Compatibility and Target Compatibility it says: "$JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 : 1.8 (Java 8) (Unresolved reference: JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)" but I don't know how to fix this.

Snippets of my app level build gradle:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true

    ...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
    ...
```

Comment: Hmm that should be fixed in 5.9.0 according to https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6300

Answer (score -1):

- try this:     Syncing only active variant
              You can disable this experimental feature from
              File → Settings → Experimental → Gradle → Only sync the active variant

Comment: Doesn't make any difference.